# Setting up Windows Pycharm to use Git on my linux server

Tags: linux, git, pycharm

So I'm trying to do something probably pretty simple but can't figure it out of course. I have a VM on my network running CentOS and I installed Git using the guide. Now I'm on my Windows PC using Pycharm trying to setup Git but the setup asks for where the git.exe file is and can't seem to navigate to my CentOS VM within pycharm to point it anywhere. I tried \IP Address but that didn't work. Is there somewhere on the Linux vm I need to do to allow the windows Pycharm to reach it? I'm new to this on both sides lol.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to access a Git-Repository in your local Linux network. In that case you need to be able to access these files with your Windows machine in order to push/fetch your changes from/to it. A simple way to do it, could be set up file sharing as explained here [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) and then clone and handle it as any local Git-Repository (see e.g. [link](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/basic-git-commands) - with local Repos the file path is used instead of the URL).

An even simpler way could be to create a hosted online Git-Repository (e.g. on Github) even if you are a sole contributor, maybe make it a private one, if you don't want to make the contents public.

Comment: ok i got Samba working and created a drive letter on my PC to browse to my linux server hosting Git. Now pycharm is looking for git.exe, how do find that in linux or am i doing this wrong in pycharm?

Comment: If you already have Git installed, check if under Settings/Version Control/Git the path to git.exe is set (typically in Program Files)

Comment: the git install is on a separate linux CentOS machine which is where i'm running into the problem with my Windows pycharm.

Comment: By principle you need Git installed on every machine with which you wish to manage Git repositories.

Comment: Really? That doesn't seem right but I'll have to look into it. I thought I would have git setup on something and it basically acts as a server for all project people can grab and change and upload back.